# Template Maps. .. can we?

Tags: c++, templates, maps

I want to create a container (preferably map) that holds values of discrete type:

```
KEY     Value
Omega    1.9  
Output   myoutput.out  
sizex    82  
#####    ###
```

where the key is = **"std::string"** and the value is either of **"INT/ DOUBLE/ String"**

I tried declaring something like.

```
template<typename T>  
map<string, typename T> mymap;
```

But sure it doesn't works.

:(

I know that there is simple way, splitting them into different variables but that just results in code bloat. Also I am clear about the fact,
`std::map<key_value key, class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key,T>>`
needs to know information about "key" and "value" to generate space during compilation.

But this problem is bugging me for quite a while and just need to sort it :D
Can someone walk me through this :D

Comment: You could try Boost.variant as the mapped type. But are you sure that you actually need a `map`?

Comment: Perhaps a `data_type` of [`Boost.any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/any.html)?

Comment: Using "Boost.variant", a new library, is a little cumbersome i guess.

Comment: anyways Map is not the only thing. I want to use the "values" for the corresponding "keys" from the container for further calculations and since maps gives the results within O(N) -- (N-- no. of elements) I decided to go with maps.

Comment: What do you really achieve by storing `int` and `double` as binary values instead of strings? It looks like a configuration file, is performance important? Just deserialize the values when retrieving from the map, and assert that the numeric conversion worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <map>

using namespace std;


union mytypes_t {
  int c;
  double i;
  char* c;
} 

int main()
{
    Map<int, mytypes_t> myObject;
}
```

More on [unions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/)

Comment: @Jason Your right, my bad. I wrote this off the editor. But my point is valid non the less.

Comment: This approach has the horrible side effect of forcing you to manage memory that is stored in an union (i.e. to store a string you would need to dynamically allocate memory, and then you will need to walk through the map at the end of the run and call `delete[]` on those elements for which the active member is the `char*` but not if the active member is anything else... I'd rather stay away from that complexity.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I agree with you, but to solve that you could always use a smart pointer.

Comment: No, you cannot and should not. If you could use a smart pointer, you would also be able to use `std::string`, and then there would be no need for the smart pointer. But unions in C++03 only allow POD types, and while unions in C++11 do allow any type, you still need to manage the lifetime of the active member of the union manually, which in itself forces you to track the type that is stored... if you are going to do that in the first place, then use a  variant (boost variant, even your own variant) or type-erasure (boost any)

Comment: @DOOM You could use map<string, void*> and then you can tell the type by it is size.

Comment: Once you store it as a `void*` you loose the type information, including size.

Comment: i agree with David.. For now the `struct` seems to be a solution. Thanks guys for your help .. :D

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution, as you mentioned is separating the data into three different arrays and writing a wrapper that will find the element in the appropriate container (assuming that the code that performs the lookup does know the type of the variable, else even this becomes complicated).

Alternatively you can use a variant type (boost variant) or type erasure (boost any) to use a container that will handle the different types. If you cannot use boost, implementing some simple type erasure is not *that* complicated, but I would stay away from it unless you *really* need it (i.e. prefer a pre canned over-the-shelf solution to your own square wheel)